# C# Not able to post data using HttpRequestMessage and getting 400 status

Tags: c#, json, http-post, httpclient

I tried a few different ways I can't get **pipelineId** to post (receive 400), see code below:

```
{
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_serviceConfig.DataGapsBaseUrl);
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/piper/jobs");

                var jsonContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    pipelineId = _serviceConfig.DataPipelineId
                }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                
                request.Content = jsonContent;

                var token = await GetToken();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.ToString());

                var result = await client.SendAsync(request);

                var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                var jobId = json["id"].ToString();
                return jobId;
            }
        }
```

When I use Postman same actions as above, I get 200 status and results:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are using async await , use it everywhere and this syntax is more usuall

```
using HttpClient client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri) };

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.ToString());

var jsonContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    pipelineId = _serviceConfig.DataPipelineId
                }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

 var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, jsonContent);

 var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
var createTime =  (string) jObj["createTime"]; //I can't see Id in Postman
```

Comment: Result is coming back null and getting 400 status. The issue is above this code block.

Comment: Request.Content = jsonContent;   // value set in jsonContent  not coming over

Comment: Basically, the post body is not getting there

Comment: "{\"status\":400,\"message\":\"BAD_REQUEST\",\"details\":[\"GDP400000: The request was invalid or cannot be otherwise served.\"]}"

Comment: {Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://dataopspoc.ops.afsaousc.us:6055/piper/jobs', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Authorization: Bearer eyMi0yM2RhZjk0MjgY2x1c3RlciIsInZpZXctcGlwZWxpbmUiLCJlZGl0LXRlbXBsYXRlIiwiZGF
  Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:08afd478-a5bc-46b5-91cb-7afaf94e6679
  Request-Id: |a746c32fcd6a1f20429f2e84170a8fcf.63f53df6cb3ea999.
  traceparent: 00-a746c32fcd6a1f20429f2e84170a8fcf-63f53df6cb3ea999-00
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 53
}}

Comment: @Chaka The code I posted was used hundreds time and never failed. You better use a debugger to check what is value of _serviceConfig.DataPipelineId and post piper/jobs action code if it is possible

Comment: You gave me good code. The json I was passing was incorrect. Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For starters:

- You forgot to serialize the StringContent

```
var jsonContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    pipelineId = _serviceConfig.DataPipelineId
                }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Change the following using await aswell to prevent thread-locking

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Please note if your client is a singleton and you are setting authentication from an async context it might be overwritten by another call either recreate client or perhaps set the authorization on the HttpRequestMessage:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/piper/jobs");
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.ToString()
```

Comment: "{\"status\":400,\"message\":\"BAD_REQUEST\",\"details\":[\"GDP400000: The request was invalid or cannot be otherwise served.\"]}"

Comment: {Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://dataopspoc.ops.afsaousc.us:6055/piper/jobs', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Authorization: Bearer eyJraWQiOiIxNDA2ZGQ3MC0zOWQ4LTRjOGItYjI1Mi0yM2RhZjk0Mjg0NTMiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJjZGlzcG9sbGluZ3N2YyIsImF1ZCI6ImRhdGFvcHNzdWl0ZS1jbGktY2xpZW50IiwidXNlci1hdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJ2aWV3LXRlbXBsYXRlIiwiZWRpdC1waXBlbGlb3ea999-00
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 53
}}

Answer (score -1):

Sorry Guys, my fault I need to send this:

{"pipelineId":"zxxzxzxzxz18","inputs":{"Batch_Id":9999}}

Needed to figure out how to hand double quotes and it fixed the issue.